# C++ builder program using key-input when launching

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I want to change program behavior whether optional key input is there or not.I wrote Form1 constructor like followings:

```
bool controlled = false;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    if( GetKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000 ){
        Label1->Caption = "Left Control";
        controlled = true;
    }
    else
        controlled = false;

}
```

Program can detect key-input (ex. Left Control key pressed when launching from windows explorer by double-clicking).
But If you use key-input, the program will hide in bottom most. And Form is inactive.
I used win32 system call something like topmost.etc, in that case Form can be topmost but still inactive.
What should I do for seamless operation.

I tried some win32 system calls.

Can be done by the following code.

```
void SetForegroundWindowEx(HWND hWnd)
{
    int targetThread, selfThread;

    //
    targetThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL);
    selfThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
    AttachThreadInput(selfThread, targetThread, TRUE );

    //
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

    //
    AttachThreadInput(selfThread, targetThread, FALSE );
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000) {
        Label1->Caption = "Left Control";
        controlled = true;

        // Bring the form to the foreground and activate it
            SetForegroundWindowEx(Handle);


    }


}
```